# Write to a config file for Discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot using Discord.py and have a few commands that I would like to run and have the data written to a json file. Right now when I run one of the commands, it just over writes the entire json file.

```
@bot.command()
async def setstatus(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send('The server status channel has been set to ' + arg)
    newArg = ""

    for character in arg:
        if character.isalnum():
            newArg += character

    data['statusChannel'] = newArg
    writeToJSON(path, fileName, data)
```

This is the writeToJSON function

```
def writeToJSON(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: What is the `writeToJSON` code? What's the contents of path/filename/data?

Comment: What's exactly your question here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text to file you need to use the `'a'` parameter in the `open` function and not `'w'`, that overwrite the whole file.

```
def writeToJSON(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
```

Because you can't add data to json I think is better to use pickle.

You can use pickle to read and write objects to file. With pickle you can read and add more data to your file. If your data is a list you do this like that:

```
# data is list in this example
def writeToJSON(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    # read old data
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'rb') as handle:
       old_data = pickle.load(handle)
       save_data = old_data + data  # add the new data to old
       # wirte the new data
       with open(filePathNameWExt, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(save_data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: You cannot really append to a JSON file

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Is there a better file format to use then?

Comment: you can make the data a list, or something like that, and use pickle

Comment: Not really @JustinWilker, the best would be to use a relational database

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are meaning by make the data a list. I'm just trying to save one thing to the file at a time. Using the code provided by @jacobgalam, I get the error 

https://pastebin.com/rpUA7sZc

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the reasons why JSON files are bad, you cannot overwrite a single value, it will always overwrite the whole file. If you have multiple commands running at the same time a race condition may occur, if you don't want to switch to a relational database you can use something like an `asyncio.Lock`.

```py
lock = asyncio.Lock() # Remember to import asyncio

async def write_to_json(path, filename, data):
    async with lock: # acquiring the lock, it will be released at the end of the context manager 
        file_path = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
        with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)
```